# Uiwebview loading too long

Tags: iphone, html, uiwebview, loading

I am using Uiwebview to load html-files for an Iphone-app. Switching between different pages lasts some seconds where the screen remains white. Are there any ideas how to get rid of the loading time, for example by preloading the next page?

Comment: You can use Grand Central Dispatch.......

Comment: Use a another webview with `hidden=YES` and load the page.Hide the current webview and make the other visible when you want you wanted to display the next page.
[note:Load the backup webview from secondary thread]